# Layout for two JLists separated by a "middle" panel? (Java Swing)

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager

I am using BoxLayout to layout 3 components in a row horizontally - two JLists (J1 and J2) and a JPanel in between (X).

```
---------------
|             |
|             |
|  J1  X  J2  |
|             |
|             |
---------------
```

The problem I am having is that BoxLayout is making each column equal size, but what I want is for X to be its smallest size and J1 and J2 to take up all the available horizontal space. How can I do this? Basically, the look I am going for is something like this.

[image]

Comment: Post SSCCE. As far as I know Box Layout allows different sizes of columns.

Comment: What is the preferred size of `X`?

Comment: Why do this need a SSCCE? It's two JLists separated by a middle component, all using the same layout manager. Can't get more clearer than that.

Comment: If you post an SSCCE, I (& possibly others) can play with it to check answers before posting them.  But hey, it's your problem, so if you are not that interested in an answer, don't bother.  BTW - I don't believe @StanislavL would have been notified of your comment.  Add `@PersonName` to ensure they are notified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html).

The center buttons would be contained in a JPanel.

The JList, button JPanel, and JList would be contained in 1 row with 3 elements across the row.

Comment: Yes, I ended up doing this. I made both JLists have a `weightx`/`weighty` of 1 and a `fill` of `BOTH`; I made the middle panel have a `weightx`/`weighty` of 0 and a `fill` of `NONE`.

Answer (score 0):

Put a horizontal glue between the JLists:

```
box.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue())
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use the `setPreferredSize` and `setMinimumSize` methods. These can be used in conjunction with this method to base your pane size off the screen size:

`screen Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();`

although you might just have your window as a fixed size.

For the lists you should add the items to a `JPanel`, set the size of the panel based on the number of objects and then set the `JScrollPane` view to that `JPanel` with `setViewPort` to ensure your scroll pane is the right size.

Comment: See also [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513)?

Answer (score -1):

```
    JPanel panel_20 = new JPanel();
    tabbedPane_2.addTab("New tab", null, panel_20, null);
    panel_20.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel_20, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

    JPanel panel_24 = new JPanel();
    panel_24.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(3, 3, 3, 3));
    panel_20.add(panel_24);
    panel_24.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

    JList list_7 = new JList();
    list_7.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED, null, null, null, null));
    panel_24.add(list_7);

    JPanel panel_25 = new JPanel();
    panel_20.add(panel_25);
    panel_25.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel_25, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    JButton btnNewButton_4 = new JButton(">");
    panel_25.add(btnNewButton_4);

    JButton btnNewButton_5 = new JButton("<");
    panel_25.add(btnNewButton_5);

    JPanel panel_26 = new JPanel();
    panel_26.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(3, 3, 3, 3));
    panel_20.add(panel_26);
    panel_26.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

    JList list_8 = new JList();
    list_8.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED, null, null, null, null));
    panel_26.add(list_8, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```